# how to casting session to list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

First I am assigning a list values to Session like this

```
HttpContext.Session[cont + "schedule"] = objupload.schedule;
```

It is saving fine,

After that I want to retrieve the values from the session, then I am using this

```
objupload.schedule=HttpContext.Session[cont + "schedule"];
```

When I am using this, I am getting this error

> 'Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

My question is, ia casting possible for list conversion and is there any other solution  for retrieving a value from the session?

Comment: tell us more about your objUpload object

Comment: You can use an explicit cast or the 'as' keyword to cast it. Implicit casting means that you're not telling it what it should be casted to and there's no implicit conversion method defined that it can find. So you must EXPLICITLY tell it what you want to cast to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can typecast it, something like this should work.

```
objupload.schedule = (List<SomeClass>)HttpContext.Session[cont + "schedule"];
```

here replace `SomeClass` with your class.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast an object from a session by:

```
        if (HttpContext.Session[cont + "schedule"] != null)
        {
            objupload.schedule = HttpContext.Session["Current"] as (List<SomeClass>);
        }
```